# Python using IMAP how do I read emails from inbox from a given date and time until now with a given subject

Tags: python, imap

I am able to read messages with a given subject .

First in my initialization I log in mail using IMAP

```
self.mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imapName, imapPort)
```

then I can read emails with given subject using this method:

```
def readEmailWithSubject(self, mySubject, fromDateTime):
    self.mail.list()
    self.mail.select("inbox")
    subjectStr = '(HEADER Subject ' + "\"" + mySubject + "\"" + ')'
    result, UIDemailsWithGivenSubject = self.mail.uid('search', None, subjectStr)
```

What I really want is to use fromDateTime  which is in UTC Zulu format i.e

```
2019-02-28T19:43:42.529791Z
```

and read emails on inbox with given subject only from that date/Time until NOW (the current time program is running).  It is important that I utilize the minutes . So in my case above all emails from UTC time: Feb 28, Time 19th hour and 43 min.  Emails arrive every 30 min so I need to make sure I utilize minutes as well.

Comment: You cannot do this generally with only server side searching.  IMAP search language only supports a granularity of the day (with no specific time zone).  You will need to search, grab the metadata (eg, the INTERNALDATE field), and then do a local filter again.

Comment: Using UIDs, all newer emails are supposed to have larger UIDs.  Can you store that between runs and get messages with UIDs higher than what you had before?  `SEARCH SUBJECT '....'  UID LAST+1:*`.  This can work well on well behaved servers, if you do not move messages back into your INBOX.

Comment: I was afraid of that , I will have to keep data between searches

Comment: This email gets otehr emails for different reason so my last UID wont be the right one.    Thats why I am using the subject

Comment: Sorry we crossed wire, just realized, This email inbox gets other emails for different reason so my last UID wont be the right one. Thats why I am using the subject

Comment: Yes, use both.  You can do a search with more than one term.

Comment: I will consolidate some my advice into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this generally with only server side searching. IMAP search language only supports a granularity of the day (with no specific time zone). You will need to search, grab the metadata (eg, the INTERNALDATE field), and then do a local filter again.

Another alternative is to use the guarantees provided by UIDs.  New messages always increase in UID (assuming your mailbox isn't regenerated), so you can use this to detect new messages.

If you keep track of the highest UID you've processed so far then you can search only for messages with newer UIDs.  Assuming your server is well implemented, and you don't move messages into the folder, you can add the search term `UID n:*`, where n is one higher than the highest UID you've processed.  This means a range from n to the highest message in the box.

```
searchStr = '(UID %d:* HEADER Subject ' + "\"" + mySubject + "\"" + ')' % uidStart
```

And store (uid + 1) somewhere (database, on disk, in memory, etc.) for any message you process that's larger than the current largest UID.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might work.

At init time, I delete (archive) all emails with given subject of interest.  Then save date and time, each time I read inbox with given subject and decipher through beginning date to dateNow and how many I expect. then archive those emails for next time around

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to filter out some of the search results you get back, but the general logic would be:

- issue IMAP search for both subject and date constraint together
- construct an ID set out of the resultant set of IDs that Search returned
- provide the ID set to the server with a Fetch for the Date header
- iterate through the returned dates, trim off "Date:" via split, trim whitespace
- convert the remaining string to a datetime usable for compare
- discard any IDs that have a datetime that is outside your desired window